# How to force www. version

Tags: wordpress, bitnami

I have a problem with my bitnami wordpress hosted on Google cloud.
I have both the www and the non-www version running in parallel.
I want to have all the non-www traffic 301 to the www version.

I added these lines into the conf file:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

But it does not fix the issue. Anyone has a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Bitnami Engineer here,

To redirect all the requests to the www domain, you can make the following changes in the `/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf`

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(localhost|127.0.0.1)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com$1 [R=301,L]
...

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(localhost|127.0.0.1)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com$1 [R=301,L]
...
```

and restart Apache

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache
```

More information here: https://docs.bitnami.com/google/apps/wordpress/administration/use-single-domain/